# Not able to find Derby Driver Template in Eclipse

Tags: driver, derby, eclipse-juno

Might be a silly question, but this is creating a problem. I am not able to find Derby Driver Template in Eclipse, not sure why?! I want to add Derby as my DB and build an app, tried searching everywhere online, didn't find any help. If you could let me know how to add a new Driver Template, it'd be great.

I checked in Data Management -> Driver Definition.

My exact problem, in the below link, step 4 -> I don't see Derby.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html

Comment: Found a solution myself, rather stupid solution at that. "Data Tools Platform Enablement Extender SDK" was not latest version, just updated it and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to a latest version of Eclipse and it still has the same problem.
In my case, I selected the latest version of the drive in name / type and then clicked on the jar list, selected the driver and click edit, put the finder where your drive is and click open.
Here is the [link](https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/add-mysql-jdbc-driver-to-eclipse.html) that helped me fix the problem, which is about mysql connect but I think it works for all drives.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution myself, rather stupid solution at that. "Data Tools Platform Enablement Extender SDK" was not latest version, just updated it and it worked!